# How to add attribute to every table row only when one is hovered (and not the hovered row) via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, hover, jquery-hover

What's the best way to add an attribute (like -webkit-filter:blur(2px); for example) to every row only when the user hovers on a row and not have it set on the row being hovered? So basically every row would be blurred except the one the user is hovering on and the effect would go away once the user's mouse isn't hovering on any row (all of the rows would become readable again without any effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/nywwezye/)***

Set all to blur on a class name or rule based on selection if setting class names is not as relevant (such as `#myTable tbody tr`), remove the class name on hover. In order for the table to only show the blur when focused, use `:hover` in the css definition.

```js
$(function(){
   $("#myTable tr").addClass("unfocused");
   $('.unfocused').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('unfocused');
   },function(){
    $(this).addClass('unfocused');
   });
});
```

```css
#myTable:hover .unfocused{
 filter: blur(2px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
 -moz-filter: blur(2px);
 -o-filter: blur(2px);
 -ms-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td><td>World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add `table:hover .unfocused` instead of `.unfocused` so the blur will only apply when hovering on the table.

Comment: @Zenorbi - I missed the part about having it only apply when the table is hovered. Your css suggestion is more viable then the js edit I made actually, I am going to change it :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I suck when it comes to jQuery, but reading your code actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is this http://jsfiddle.net/n3a1d4z8/

```
$('.tg tr').hover( function(){    
    $('.tg tr').toggleClass('blur');
    $(this).toggleClass('blur');
});
```

The CSS filter property only works in Chrome 31+, Safari 7+, Opera 18+. No Firefox or Explorer. So check the example in one of the supported browser to see the blur effect :)